# How to use CASE WHEN condition with MAX() function

Tags: mysql

I used the `LAG()` window function to create a column of the lag difference. Now I want to create an additional column which looks at all the lag differences and ONLY labels the maximum difference as 'MAX' and the minimum value as 'MIN'. All other values should be empty.

I have created a table which has the lag_difference as the last column. I tried to use a `CASE WHEN lag_difference = MAX(lag_difference_column) THEN 'MAX'` 
but I am not able to perform a conditional on an aggregation. Maybe I can generate a static value with a subquery to spit out a MAX value that I can compare to, but I want the MAX to be dynamic so that if more values are added the `MAX(lag_difference_column)` also has the possibility to change.

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN lag_difference = MAX(lag_difference) THEN 'MAX'
     WHEN lag_difference = MIN(lag_difference) THEN 'MIN'
     END AS label
FROM(
    SELECT *, pay_amount - LAG(pay_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY full_name ORDER BY pay_month) AS lag_difference
    FROM
        (WITH top_ten AS
        (SELECT customer_id
        FROM payment
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
        LIMIT 10)

        SELECT
        DATE_TRUNC('month', payment_date) AS pay_month,
        first_name||' '||last_name AS full_name,
        COUNT(*) AS pay_count,
        SUM(amount) AS pay_amount
        FROM customer c
        JOIN top_ten
        ON c.customer_id = top_ten.customer_id
        JOIN payment p
        ON top_ten.customer_id = p.customer_id
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        ORDER BY 2, 1) sub
) sub2
```

I expected to get an extra column next to the lag_difference column where the maximum of that column is labeled as MAX and the minimum as MIN. However, I can't use a CASE WHEN where the condition is dependent on an aggregation.

Any simple work around this problem?

Comment: Your query is in a mess.  Please add sample data and the expected output.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86612/34681

Comment: Sorry for the lack of proper syntax structure. I just started SQL and programming in general about a month ago..Just wanted to know if aggregate function can be used in a CASE WHEN condition