# CASE WHEN condition with MAX() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, aggregate-functions

There are a lot questions on CASE WHEN topic, but the closest my question is related to this [How to use CASE WHEN condition with MAX() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055639/how-to-use-case-when-condition-with-max-function) query which has not been resolved.

Here is some of my sample data:

| date | debet |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 | 57190.33 |
| 2022-07-14 | 815616516.00 |
| 2022-07-15 | 40866.67 |
| 2022-07-14 | 1221510.00 |

So, I want to all records for the last two dates and three additional columns: `sum(sales)` for the previous day, `sum` for the current day and the difference between them:

```sql
SELECT
    [debet],
    [date] , 
    SUM( CASE WHEN [date] = MAX(date)     THEN [debet] ELSE 0 END ) AS sum_act, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN [date] = MAX(date) - 1 THEN [debet] ELSE 0 END ) AS sum_prev , 
    (
        SUM( CASE WHEN [date] = MAX(date)     THEN [debet] ELSE 0 END ) 
        -
        SUM( CASE WHEN [date] = MAX(date) - 1 THEN [debet] ELSE 0 END )  
    ) AS diff 
FROM
    Table 
WHERE
    [date] = ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table WHERE date < ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table) )
    OR
    [date] = ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table WHERE date = ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table ) )
GROUP BY
    [date],
    [debet]
```

Further, of course, it informs that I can't use the aggregate function inside `CASE WHEN`. Now I use  this combination: `sum(CASE WHEN [date] = dateadd(dd,-3,cast(getdate() as date)) THEN [debet] ELSE 0 END)`. But here every time I need to make an adjustment for weekends and holidays. The question is, is there any other way than using 'getdate' in 'case when' Statement to get max date?

Expected result:

| date | sum_act | sum_prev | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 | 97190.33 | 0.00 | 97190.33 |
| 2022-07-14 | 0.00 | 508769.96 | -508769.96 |

Comment: please include some sample data and expected result as text (not as image) and explain the necessary logic required

Comment: Your query is invalid: you have an extra `THEN [debet] ELSE 0 END )` in there (there are _four_ `CASE WHEN` keywords but _five_ `ELSE .. END` keywords)

Comment: `[date] = ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table WHERE date = ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM Table ) )` <-- There's a lot of redundancy here...

Comment: What actually is your question? You've posted a query and some comments, but haven't actually asked anything.

Comment: You might have an XY problem. Can you post a description of the question you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks @Dai, corrected. As for the query in 'where', I don't know how to write it differently, but it works

Comment: @Squirrel I added a question at the end. As for the expected result and the initial data, the preview shows normal tables, but when publishing, only text. Have no clue what to do.. sorry, it's my first post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dense_rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to filter the last 2 dates in your table. After that you can use either conditional case expression with `sum()` to calculate the required value

```
select [date],
       sum_act  = sum(case when rn = 1 then [debet] else 0 end),
       sum_prev = sum(case when rn = 2 then [debet] else 0 end),
       diff     = sum(case when rn = 1 then [debet] else 0 end)
                - sum(case when rn = 2 then [debet] else 0 end)
from
(
    select *, rn = dense_rank() over (order by [date] desc)
    from   tbl 
) t
where rn <= 2
group by [date]
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28922c6d9f258cc17f7097afcb1c9f75)

Comment: Thanks a lot! To be honest I never used dense_rank(), now I see that it works well.. although in the result is a little less rows, but I think I'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Get the sums for the last three dates
2. Show the results for the last two dates.

Well, we could also get all daily sums in step 1, but we just need the last three in order to calculate the sums for the last two days, so why aggregate more data than necessary?

Here is the query. You may have to put the date column name in brackets in SQL Server, as date is a keyword in SQL.

```
select top(2)
  date,
  sum_debit_current,
  sum_debit_previous,
  sum_debit_current - sum_debit_previous as diff
(
  select
    date,
    sum(debet) as sum_debit_current,
    lag(sum(debet)) over (order by date) as sum_debit_previous
  from table
  where date in (select distinct top(3) date from table order by date desc)
  group by date
)
order by date desc;
```

(SQL Server uses `TOP(n)` instead of standard SQL `FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS` and while `SELECT DISTINCT TOP(3) date` looks like "get the top 3 rows, then apply distinct on their date", it is really "apply distinct on the dates, then get the top 3" like in standard SQL.)